# PySide2.QtWidgets.QxxxxLayout.addWidget called with wrong argument types

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, pyside2

I'm trying to add FigureCanvasQTAgg argument as widget to some layout using addWidget funtion and TypeError occured. This Error appers only when trying to run my standalone appliciation that was built using pyinstaller. When running the script directly everything works well.

I'm using `python=3.6`, `PySide2=5.12.3`, `pyInstaller=3.4`

```py
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox, QLineEdit, QComboBox, QWidget
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class TasksConfigCreatorAdapter(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TasksConfigCreatorAdapter, self).__init__()
        self.dialog = Ui_TasksConfigCreatorDialog()
        self.dialog.setupUi(self)  
        self.figure = None
        self.setupCanvasLayout()

    def setupCanvasLayout(self):
        if self.figure is None:
            self.figure = plt.figure()
            self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
            self.figure.set_facecolor("white")
            self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, None)
            self.dialog.canvasLayout.addWidget(self.canvas, *(0, 0))
            self.dialog.canvasLayout.addWidget(self.toolbar, *(1, 0))
```

```
TypeError: 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QGridLayout.addWidget' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide2.QtWidgets.QGridLayout.addWidget(FigureCanvasQTAgg, int, int)
Supported signatures:
  PySide2.QtWidgets.QGridLayout.addWidget(PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget, int, int, PySide2.QtCore.Qt.Alignment=Default(Qt.Alignment))
  PySide2.QtWidgets.QGridLayout.addWidget(PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget, int, int, int, int, PySide2.QtCore.Qt.Alignment=Default(Qt.Alignment))
  PySide2.QtWidgets.QGridLayout.addWidget(PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget)
```

Comment: It might be a workaround only, but have you tried setting the default value from first overload of `addWidget` explicitly?

Comment: Yes, I've tried this workaround without any success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this issue by adding `PyQt5` module to the exclude list in the spec file.
When trying to create the standalone in one folder mode, I figured out that `PyQt5` files was added as well as `PySide2` files which interrupt and cause this issue to happend.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

```
TypeError: 'qRegisterResourceData' called with wrong argument types:
  qRegisterResourceData(int, str, str, str)
Supported signatures:
  qRegisterResourceData(int, unicode, unicode, unicode)
```

My mistake was that I was using Python3 and didn't use `-py3` flag to compile the qrc file, where the default is Python2.

```
Usage: C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\PySide\pyside-rcc.exe  [options] <inputs>

Options:
    -o file           Write output to file rather than stdout
    -py2              Generate code for any Python v2.x version (default)
    -py3              Generate code for any Python v3.x version
    -name name        Create an external initialization function with name
    -threshold level  Threshold to consider compressing files
    -compress level   Compress input files by level
    -root path        Prefix resource access path with root path
    -no-compress      Disable all compression
    -version          Display version
    -help             Display this information
```